# Unity3D Android visual artifacts

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, graphics, artifacts

Since a while ago I started having some artifacts on some android devices. I have checked build settings, I was disabling code stripping and setting all options to the default ones - nothing worked out.
This visual interference (see screenshot) happens at least in Note II and HTC One Mini/2. Nexus 5 exhibited very minor interferences. 
Any help would be highly appreciated!

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYMls.png)

Comment: Are you using any UI plugin like nGUI? this happen to me sometime and solved rebuilding the atlas.

Comment: Hey, Joreldraw! No, I am not using any UI plugins..

Answer (score 1):

If you're having issues with rendering like I was - try to check your **main camera -> Clear Flags** property.
In my case, one of my background layers (SpriteRenderer) were switching their alpha values. At some point all layers would be half-transparent. This is when the problem occurs. In order to fix it you need to unset the "Don't Clear" value in "Clear Flags" property.

Answer (score 0):

which Unity version are you using? Can you make sure to use ETC1 compression (+alpha if needed) and try again on those devices?